# Salesforce MobileSDK app login via SAML SSO still required to perform Salesforce MFA

Tags: single-sign-on, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mfa

My org has an SAML 2.0 Single Sign-On enabled with:

Azure AD:

- SAML Identity Type: Federation ID
- SAML Identity Location: Subject
- Service Provider Initiated Request Binding: HTTP Redirect
- Use Salesforce MFA for this SSO Provider: `false`

---

When a log-in attempt is made on a browser / Salesforce app, it behaves as expected, and user is NOT required to go through Salesforce's MFA (since the SSO provider already implement MFA on their side)

On our custom Android / iOS app, built using Salesforce MobileSDK, user is still requested to perform Salesforce's MFA after SSO's log-in flow succeeds.

What can I do to ensure that users logging in via SAML SSO are not required to perform MFA on Salesforce side?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.